# How do I see the statistics for rcov from the command line?

Tags: rspec, rake, code-coverage, specs, rcov

I'm running the built-in rake task to generate rcov reports:

rake spec:rcov

This generate files in my coverage directory, but I would like to see some aggregate stats output to the command console.

Something like the total coverage and number of lines being tested in a format similar to what you get when you run "rake stats"

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the --text-summary option to my rcov.opts and it outputs the data I need.